# How to exit dropdown menu in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver with Chrome. I am able to select item from dropdown menu and it works fine.

But it there is no item in dropdown items after that I cannot select any other field.

I put this is `try catch block` so it goes to next steps. If I try to select other field and `sendKeys` it still adds text to dropdown search bar.

And after that when I try to click on button I get error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (698, 686). Other element would receive the click: 
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.80)
```

I can see in UI that cursor stays at dropdown search bar. How can I exit it? I tried to click on it again to minimize it but it wouldn't

Comment: can you share link to web page?

Comment: have you tried to shift the focus to another element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes moving focus worked. Previously I was trying to do `find_element...click()` that didn't worked. But below did !!     `ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_name('name')).click().perform()`

Comment: Do I need to import something to use ActionChains?

Comment: yes you'll have to import it something like `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
`

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

WebDriver driver;

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("elementID")).click().perform();

//you can use this to move to any other element not intercepted by dropdown list
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is much more useful to OP and future readers if you explain *how* and *why* your code solves the problem